# ORA-00905 missing keyword

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to execute the following code in sqlplus through a sql file:

```
connect sys/knl_test7 as sysdba    
grant sysdba to user1 identified by user1;    
grant sysoper to user2 identified by user2;

variable c number;

begin    
  :c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;    
  for i in 3 .. 98 loop    
    dbms_sql.parse(:c, 'grant sysdba to user'||to_char(i)||' identified by user'||to_char(i), dbms_sql.v7);
    dbms_lock.sleep(5);    
  end loop;    
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(:c);
  tkzpwfsync.check_condition('(select count(username) from v$pwfile_users where username like ''USER%'')=98');    
end;
/
```

However after running the script I am getting the following error:

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905 missing keyword
```

The check_condition procedure is as below, it basically verifies if the condition provided is true or not.

```
create or replace package tkzpwfsync is
  procedure check_condition(condition varchar2);
end;
/

show errors

create or replace package body tkzpwfsync is
 procedure check_condition(condition varchar2) is
  x integer;
  c number;
 begin
  x := 0;
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(c,'select 1 into x from dual where '||condition,dbms_sql.v7);
  if (x!=1) then raise_application_error(-20001,'Condition '||condition||' is not met.'); end if;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
 end;
end;
/

show errors

create public synonym tkzpwfsync for tkzpwfsync;

grant execute on tkzpwfsync to public;
```

Comment: I might be mistaken - but aren't you missing the target DB in your connect string ([user]/[pwd]@[target DB]) and the "DECLARE" of the c varialble? Should be "DECLARE c number", no?

Comment: Exactly that has to be incorporated

Comment: What is `tkzpwfsync.wait` doing? The string you're passing isn't a valid statement, so is it using that as a condition in other dynamic SQL? Teh error message suggests something more fundamental though. (The @DBNAME doesn't need to be supplied if you're connecting to the local DB via ORACLE_SID, rather than over SQL\*Net; and the bind variable is fine if unusual when a PL/SQL variable would do; and the parse works, but execute immediate is more common).

Comment: What you have works fine, if I exclude the `wait` call. So I still think it's going to be the `wait` call generating the error; did you show the whole stack trace, or did it have another line saying `ORA-06512: at line 8`?

Comment: @Rene The connect command is okay. Declare is also not needed.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes the procedure basically waits till the condition passed as argument is true. It is getting compiled correctly. And ORA-06512 is not present.

Comment: I don't see how you could get that error any other way. I'd wondered about a hidden control character or wrong line endings, but I can't make it give that error. You don't normally get a lone ORA- error from a PL/SQL block. To humour me, can you comment out the `wait` call and see what happens?

Comment: @AlexPoole The code has been working correctly without that procedure call. This is the only change that I have made in the existing code. The procedure however looks fine. Please find the procedure below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the dynamic SQL you've shown in your anonymous block - it's valid, if perhaps unusual, to use `dbms_sql` for this when it could be done with `execute immediate` but either works. And it isn't with the SQL*Plus bind variable declaration or usage, though again it would be more common to have a local PL/SQL variable rather than a client bind variable for this (as you have in your procedure), since the value of `c` doesn't need to be known outside the anonymous block. But again either works.

The problem is with your call to `tkzpwfsync.wait()`. The string you are passing is used as part of another dynamic query in that, and it's *that* generated query that is throwing the ORA-00905.

With your procedure your block gets more error detail than you have shown:

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1199
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TKZPWFSYNC.WAIT", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

The `wait()` procedure is trying to parse the SQL statement:

```
select 1 into x from dual
where (select count(username) from v$pwfile_users where username like 'USER%')=98
```

The `into x` is a PL/SQL conmstruct and not part of SQL. If you ran that directly you'd see the same ORA-00905 error because it sees the 'into' as a column alias, and then doesn't know what to do with the 'x':

```
select 1 into x from dual
where (select count(username) from v$pwfile_users where username like 'USER%')=98;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

You also aren't actually executing the query - [`parse` does execute DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68277) (so your grant in the anonymous block works), but doesn't execute DML. If it did then it would get an ORA-01403 if the condition was not met; it's safer here to use an aggregate so you always get one row back.

You can modify the procedure to do:

```
  dbms_sql.parse(c,'select count(*) from dual where '||condition,dbms_sql.v7);
  dbms_sql.define_column(c, 1, x);
  r := dbms_sql.execute(c);
```

so it becomes:

```
procedure wait(condition varchar2) is
  x integer;
  c number;
  r integer;
begin
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(c,'select count(*) from dual where '||condition,dbms_sql.v7);
  dbms_sql.define_column(c, 1, x);
  r := dbms_sql.execute(c);
  if dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c) > 0 then 
    dbms_sql.column_value(c, 1, x); 
  end if;

  if (x!=1) then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Condition '||condition||' is not met.');
  end if;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
end;
/
```

That now works, and does throw the ORA-20001 if the condition is not met.

It's simpler to use `execute immediate` here too, as @Mottor showed:

```
procedure wait(condition varchar2) is
  x integer;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from dual where '||condition into x;

  if (x!=1) then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Condition '||condition||' is not met.');
  end if;
end;
/
```

... but maybe there's a reason you want to use `dbms_sql.v7` instead of native execution.

I'm not sure that wait is really necessary though; the entries will have been added to that view as the users were created, so they will all exist before you make the call. It makes slightly more sense as a check rather than a wait, with your amended procedure name, but still not sure it's necessary - if the count didn't match then either an error would have been raised already by a grant failing, or you already had users with SYSDBA privileges. so the count will be higher. It just doesn't seem very useful. (I won't even ask why you need 98 users with SYSDBA privs; hopefully you're just experimenting, but if so I'd use a less dangerous role).

Comment: Yes the intention of the wait is to verify if the entries have been added or not. Please find the wait function above in the question.

Comment: @ShekharKanodia - OK, updated with an explanation of why your procedure is throwing that error (it's nothing to do with the anonymous block really, it would fail for any call), and a working version. I'm not sure if there's a reason you're using specifying Oracle 7 behaviour with the `dbms_sql.v7` flag; if not `execute immediate` would be a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
connect sys/knl_test7@DB_NAME as sysdba    
grant sysdba to user1 identified by user1;    
grant sysoper to user2 identified by user2;  

SET SQLBL ON;  
SET DEFINE OFF;

BEGIN
      FOR i IN 3 .. 98
      LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant sysdba to user'||TO_CHAR(i)||' identified by "user'||TO_CHAR(i)||'"';
        dbms_lock.sleep(5);
      END LOOP;
      tkzpwfsync.wait('(select count(username) from v$pwfile_users where username like ''USER%'')=98');
    END;
    /
```

Comment: plus one, definitely a case for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: Why is using `execute immediate` better than `dbms_sql.parse()`? Other than being simpler; isn't one pretty much just syntactic sugar around the other now?  And `@DB_NAME` isn't needed for a local connection - the connection wasn't the issue; and sysdba connections might not be allowed over SQL\*Net.

Comment: @AvrajitRoy Yes `@DB_NAME` is not needed. The connection is not the issue as mentioned by Alex as well.

Comment: If you can try commenting your call to procedure wait() and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:177412348070) for sample with dbms_sql.parse

> You do not SELECT ... INTO ... in dynamic sql. You just select and bind the output columns.

Here is with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY POINT_NET.tkzpwfsync
IS
   PROCEDURE wait (condition VARCHAR2)
   IS
      x   INTEGER;
   BEGIN
      x := 0;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from dual where ' || condition INTO x;
      IF (x != 1) THEN
         raise_application_error (-20001, 'Condition ' || condition || ' is not met.');
      END IF;
   END;
END;
/
```

Only to mention, that this procedure does not wait, only checks condition.

Comment: Yes the procedure was modified and hence the name wait does not make sense anymore. I have modified the name of the procedure.